# TypeError: Sequential.__init__() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

Am not able to declare the model due to problems in input_shape

```
input_shape = [x_train_scaled.shape[1]]
input_shape
```

Output -
`[6]`

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential(
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=64, input_shape=input_shape, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=64, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1)
)
model.summary()
```

Error shown : TypeError: Sequential.**init**() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

I was trying to declare a sequential model but am getting typeError

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Sequential#args_1 :

> layers: Optional list of layers to add to the model

you need to pass your layers as a list when instantiating the sequential object Instead of individual arguments like you are doing now:

```
tf.keras.Sequential(
    layers=[
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=64, input_shape=input_shape, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=64, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1)
    ],
    name=None
)
```